# How to run command as different user

Tags: su

Is it possible to run a command

- with parameters first of which starts with `-` (dash) e.g. `/usr/bin/echo -n foo`
- as different user and group, for example `apache:apache`
- using command `su`
- when login shell is set to `/sbin/nologin` ?

I tried:

- `su -s "/usr/bin/echo" -g apache apache -n foo`

  - fails with `su: invalid option -- 'n'`. It looks like first argument may not start with dash.
- `su -c "/usr/bin/echo -n foo" -g apache apache`

  - fails with `nologin: invalid option -- 'c'`. It looks like `-c` can't be used if login shell is `/sbin/nologin`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
su -s /bin/bash -c "/usr/bin/echo -n foo" -g apache apache
```

- `-s /bin/bash` overrides nologin and allows to interpret value of `-c` option
- `-c "/usr/bin/echo -n foo"` allows to avoid using dash-starting first argument

Comment: `su` in CentOS 6 doesn't support `-g <group>` option. This option is supported in CentOS 7 and 8.

Answer (score 29):

sudo to the rescue!

```
sudo -u <user> -g <group> -- echo -n foo
```

Answer (score 4):

If the user's login shell is set to `/sbin/nologin` then the user can't login and `su -` generally won't work.

But there is the `su -m` option to preserve the current user's environment and login shell:

```
su -m <user> -c "<command>"
```

For example:

```
su -m apache -c "echo hello; id"
```

Prints:

```
hello
uid=33(apache) gid=33(apache) groups=33(apache)
```